# Newline not matched in Regex while using JavaScript's ".replace"

Tags: node.js

I use node.js to read a file, save results to a variable, then replace a regex match with another string and write the result to the file.

The weirdest thing happened. I used Regex101 (with JS engine set and the same flags as my code) and it matched my desired text.
Link: https://regex101.com/r/WbmOLw/1

Implementing the exact same regex in my code, it fails to match!

I created the most minimal version representing my code:

**tst.txt (the target file):**

```
# Direct Methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .locals 2
```

This seems to be the raw string (according to CyberChef):

```
# direct methods\n.method public constructor <init>()V\n    .locals 2
```

**test.js (the code):**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mainDir = 'tst.txt'

function start(){
  fs.readFile(mainDir, "utf-8", function (err, data) {
    data = data.replace(/(constructor \<init\>[(][)]V.    \.locals )(\d+)/gms, 'BLABLAIDONTWORK')

    console.log(data) // not changed
    fs.writeFile(mainDir, data, 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
    })

  });
}

start()
```

Whatever is written in the file isn't different at all. I suspect it's a strange side effect of newline handling, but can't figure out what's causing this! any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't understand, but it's not the problem. updated a non-async/await version that fails the same.

Comment: Yeah, that makes a lot more sense now, thanks. It might be that the file saved has something like `\r\n`, and is not just `\n`, in which case two newline characters will have to be matched, not just one

Comment: I know right?? I thought so too, but a copy-paste from regexer101 still fails! (it matches on the site, not in the code! crazy)

Comment: have you tried `/(constructor\s\<init\>[(][)]V\n\s+\.locals )(\d+)/`?

Comment: I did now, still fails :O
Updating the escaped output from cyberchef (contain newlines etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you've saved very likely has `\r\n` as a newline terminator, rather than just `\n`, so the `V.` pattern does not match. I can reproduce the problem on Windows, when the file was saved with Notepad++ with the `\r\n` setting enabled. Using `\r\n` in the pattern instead worked for me:

```
data = data.replace(/(constructor \<init\>[(][)]V\r\n    \.locals )(\d+)/g, 'BLABLAIDONTWORK')
//                                               ^^^^
```

To make the pattern more flexible, to match a newline on any platform, alternate with `\n` and (for rare cases) `\r`:

```
data = data.replace(/(constructor \<init\>[(][)]V(?:\r\n|\r|\n)    \.locals )(\d+)/g, 'BLABLAIDONTWORK')
//                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(no need for the `s` modifier anymore, or the `m` modifier at all)

Comment: Ohhhh yeah man! thank you!! :) :) I sat on this for at least 3 hours!!! :) :) solved

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following regex:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mainDir = 'tst.txt'

function start(){
fs.readFile(mainDir, "utf-8", function (err, data) {
    data = data.replace(/(constructor \<init\>[(][)]V\n*\s*\.locals\s)(\d+)/gms, 'BLABLAIDONTWORK')

    console.log(data) // not changed
        fs.writeFile(mainDir, data, 'utf8', function (err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
            })

    });
}

start()
```

Comment: Works :) thanks!

What is the S thing? why is it fixing it?

Comment: The \s is a metacharacter to find whitespace character, it can be a space, tab, carriage return or new line